# Q on "hypernetworks" tape.gradient from F. Chollet's tf.keras for Researchers: Crash Course

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras, tensorflow2.0

Here's the URL to the original colab notebook:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17u-pRZJnKN0gO5XZmq8n5A2bKGrfKEUg#scrollTo=xEuWqzjlPobA

Scroll to the last cell on "Now for a quick research example: hypernetworks.":

```
input_dim = 784
classes = 10

# The model we'll actually use (the hypernetwork).
outer_model = Linear(classes)

# It doesn't need to create its own weights, so let's mark it as already built.
# That way, calling `outer_model` won't create new variables.
outer_model.built = True

# The model that generates the weights of the model above.
inner_model = Linear(input_dim * classes + classes)

# Loss and optimizer.
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)

# Prepare a dataset.
(x_train, y_train), _ = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype('float32') / 255, y_train))

# We'll use a batch size of 1 for this experiment.
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(1)

losses = []  # Keep track of the losses over time.
for step, (x, y) in enumerate(dataset):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

    # Predict weights for the outer model.
    weights_pred = inner_model(x)

    # Reshape them to the expected shapes for w and b for the outer model.
    w_pred = tf.reshape(weights_pred[:, :-classes], (input_dim, classes))
    b_pred = tf.reshape(weights_pred[:, -classes:], (classes,))

    # Set the weight predictions as the weight variables on the outer model.
    outer_model.w = w_pred
    outer_model.b = b_pred

    # Inference on the outer model.
    preds = outer_model(x)
    loss = loss_fn(y, preds)

  # Train only inner model.
  grads = tape.gradient(loss, inner_model.trainable_weights)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, inner_model.trainable_weights))

  # Logging.
  losses.append(float(loss))
  if step % 100 == 0:
    print(step, sum(losses) / len(losses))

  # Stop after 1000 steps.
  if step >= 1000:
    break
```

In the training loop, note that:

```
grads = tape.gradient(loss, inner_model.trainable_weights)
```

is outside:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
```

I thought this should be inside? It will be great if someone can reassure this is correct, and also explain what's going on with gradient tape at the same time.

If you run this notebook, whatever the code was apparently working, since you can see the loss went down on each epoch.

Comment: Update: I tried moving tape.gradient(...) inside the with block, and that also seems to work, loss also going down on each epochs. So I can’t tell which way is right and if this really matter?

Comment: Any idea why this Q is downvoted? This is new and a good thing to clarify over.

Answer (score 0):

All the examples I've seen have it outside of the with statement. Note that tape does note cease to exist outside of the with statement. The "**exit**" function is merely called.

Comment: This is not true. With the same notebook, look at the cell "8) These losses are cleared by the top-level layer at the start of each forward pass". You can see the grad calculation happens inside "with".

Comment: I guess it doesn't make a difference then.